# Vuejs: Show error messages as popups

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a login section using Vuex and Axios to authenticate the login by allowing the user to enter the email and password. I have created and stored the variables I need by using a getter. I have also, placed the tokens I needed into a function, post url and console.

But, know I need to show the responses according to the tokens being seen in the inspector/console.

What I need is to show the error messages when the user tries to login. So, when the console responds showing 200 (email and password is correct) I need it to store that token, when the console responds showing 400 (incorrect/missing characters in either email or password) I need it to print out the error messages that I have already placed with an array, lastly, when the console responds showing 401 (both email and password incorrect) I need it to print out the messageFour that is in the array.

HTML:

```
<template>
<form>
    <div class="login">
        <div>
            <input type="text" v-model="email" placeholder="Email" class="eSection" id="email">

            <p v-for="message in errorM" :key="message.errorM" v-show="message in errorM">
                {{ message }}
            </p>

            <input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Password" class="pSection" id="password">

            <p v-for="message in errorM" :key="message.errorM">
                {{message}}
            </p>

            <button type="button"  class="log" @click="login">LogIn</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            email: "test@gmail.com",
            password: "123456",
            flag: false,
            errorM:[],

            errorMessages: [
                {
                    messageOne: "The email that has been entered is incorrect. Please try again!"
                },

                {
                    messageTwo: "Email/Password is missing. Please try again!"
                },

                {
                    messageThree: "The password that has been entered is incorrect. Please try again!"
                },

                {
                    messageFour: "Both Email and Password that have been entered are incorrect!"
                },
            ]
        }
    },

    methods: {
        login: function (index) {

            axios.post(`https://api.ticket.co/auth/login`, {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                })

                .then(response => {
                    // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                    console.log(response.data)
                    console.log(response.status)
                })

                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                    console.log(e.response.status)

                    var vueObject = this

                    switch (e.response.status) {
                    case 400:
                            if(!vueObject.email || !vueObject.password){
                                vueObject.errorM.push(vueObject.errorMessages.messageTwo)
                            };

                            if(!vueObject.email){
                                vueObject.errorM.push(vueObject.errorMessages.messageOne)
                            };

                            if(!vueObject.password){
                                vueObject.errorM.push(vueObject.errorMessages.messageThree)
                            };
                            break;

                        case 401:
                        if(vueObject.email && vueObject.password == ""){
                                vueObject.errorM.push(vueObject.errorMessages.messageFour)
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                })  
        },
    },
} 
</script>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from the description what's not working, so I'll just point out some issues I see.

One thing to mention is, there is no evidence of you using vuex, no getters, no setters, no state.

Most notable is that you have the messages defined as an array of objects, which makes it difficult to look up

instead of this, which is harder to look up:

```
errorMessages: [
  {
    messageOne: "The email that has been entered is incorrect. Please try again!"
  },
  // etc... {}, {}, {}
]
```

... you should do

```
errorMessages: {
  messageOne: "The email that has been entered is incorrect. Please try again!",
  messageTwo: "Email/Password is missing. Please try again!",
  messageThree: "The password that has been entered is incorrect. Please try again!",
  messageFour: "Both Email and Password that have been entered are incorrect!",
}
```

so that you can find a message using `this.errorMessages.messageTwo`

Or better yet, define it outside of your vue component, since you're not using them in your template

```
const MESSAGE_INCORRECTEMAIL = "The email that has been entered is incorrect. Please try again!";
const MESSAGE_MISSINGFIELD = "Email/Password is missing. Please try again!";
const MESSAGE_INCORRECTPASSWORD = "The password that has been entered is incorrect. Please try again!";
const MESSAGE_INCORRECTEMAILPASSWORD = "Both Email and Password that have been entered are incorrect!";
```

and then just call them as `MESSAGE_MISSINGFIELD` from your script

From security standpoint, it's a bad idea to indicate whether the username or the password is wrong, as it makes hacking easier by confirming what usernames exist.

You can determine if the user had errors or fields are missing before sending the form for remote processing.

to do that, you would call

```
login: function (index) {
  if (this.email.trim() === '' || vueObject.password.trim() === ''){
    this.errorM.push(MESSAGE_MISSINGFIELD);
    return // <- prevents further execution
  }
  // repeat for other local validations before remote request
  // ... then process request
  axios.post(`https://api.ticket.co/auth/login`, {
```

anyway, you might also need t break your question up into individual errors you encounter.